# how to get data from table if table stored in database which is in server in ios.

Tags: objective-c

i need some help.
I am trying to fetch data which is in table format in SQL Database and my Database is in server.So can anybody tell me a procedure how to do this in efficient way.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Generally the most common approach is encapsulate the database by an REST API (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer).

However, you could look for an SQL Connection SDK provided by the manufacturer of your SQL Server. There is also an [ODBC SDK for iOS](http://odbcrouter.com/iosproxy) you can take a look at.

Comment: Hello Sir thanks for replying but still i didn't get understand..Sir i want to make list of lawyer(as table view) corresponding a view controller of every lawyer (like details of lawyer)..and these details  are stored in table format in database (like name ,location id ,experience...) and this database is in server..i want to make list of lawyers by fetching data from that database and a detail view controller corresponding each lawyer..if u have sample code of like that give me Thank you